# how to make managed wrapper class use the properties of another managed wrapper class?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, mixed-mode

The idea is that I would like to reuse code and not duplicate it. Below, UnManagedB derives from UnmanagedA. Both the structs have their corresponding managed wrappers as shown below. I would like to derive the ManagedB from ManagedA so that I can reuse the properties in ManagedA for ManagedB. The issue is both the class have their own pointers to unmanaged objects. The unmanaged object in the derived is all I want and I want all the properties to use UnManagedB pointer. Is there any way to do this?

```
struct UnManagedA {
   unsigned int size;
};

struct UnManagedB:UnManagedA {
    int length;
    int width;
};

public ref class A : public System::IDisposable {
public:
    A();
    !A();
    ~A();

    property  System::UInt32 Size {
        System::UInt32 get();
        void set(System::UInt32 value);
    }
internal:
    UnmanagedA* GetUnmanaged() { return obj1; }
private:
    UnmanagedA* obj1;
};

public ref class B : public System::IDisposable, public A {
public:
    B();
    !B();
    ~B();

    property System::UInt32 Length {
        System::UInt32 get();
        void set(System::UInt32 value);
    }

    property System::UInt32 Width {
        System::UInt32 get();
        void set(System::UInt32 value);
    }
internal:
    UnmanagedB* GetUnmanaged() { return obj2; }
private:
    UnmanagedB* obj2;
};
```

Comment: and what is the actual problem? where is the duplicate? I see no duplicates here...

Comment: what i have written is what i would want ideally but it is not possible since the base and derived have their own pointers to unmanaged objects.

Comment: what is "not possible" about it.  What's wrong with the derived and base having their own pointers?

Answer (score 0):

While they both have their own pointer to unmanaged objects, presumably those pointers point to the *exact same* unamanged object--so there should be no problem.  If you disagree describe a *specific* usage scenario where it wouldn't work correctly, and then we can better help.

Comment: the problem is during destruction. Each of the classes disposable method will be called and each will try to delete the object. each of these classes can be used as a standalone class hence they would need to delete their member pointer. So there needs to be a way to differentiate between when the pointer was set by the derived vs pointer created by the class itself.

Comment: Always have *only* the base class delete the pointer.  When you create the derived class, it should call the base class constructor and pass through the same pointer.  The derived class should not delete its pointer, because it knows the base class will call delete.

Comment: @Sriram, @Matt: Note that Matt's advice to let the base wrapper delete the pointer requires that the unmanaged class have a virtual destructor.  Another option would be for the derived class to delete the pointer and then let the base class know.  One possible way would be for the pointer to be protected instead of private, then the derived class can set it to `nullptr` (deleting `nullptr` is legal and has no effect).